# How to detect floating point errors in R

Tags: r

I was trying to transform some vectors into unit vectors. The data is structured like this:

```
    [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
a    ~       ~       ~
b    ~       ~       ~
c    ~       ~       ~
```

I want a unit vector for each row (row/magnitude) so I ran the following code:

```
cell_vectors_100 = data.frame(t(apply(cell_vectors_100, 
                                      1, 
                                      function(x)(x/sum(x)))))
```

I then went to check and make sure that the magnitudes of all my row vectors was 1 but strange things happened:

```
#These imply it worked
> sum(rowSums(cell_vectors_100))/nrow(cell_vectors_100)
[1] 1
> quantile(rowSums(cell_vectors_100))
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   1    1    1    1    1 

#this implies it did not work
> length(cell_vectors_100)
[1] 31053
> length(rowSums(cell_vectors_100)[as.numeric(rowSums(cell_vectors_100)) != 1])
[1] 142

#but here all the values that are "not 1" are 1
> head(rowSums(cell_vectors_100)[as.numeric(rowSums(cell_vectors_100)) != 1])
Blackshaw_E14_rep1:TAGCCGGCACCAGCACx Blackshaw_E14_rep1:TTCTACAGTGCCTGCAx 
                                   1                                    1 
Blackshaw_E14_rep1:TACGGGCAGTGAATTGx Blackshaw_E14_rep1:ACGATGTAGAATGTGTx 
                                   1                                    1 
Blackshaw_E14_rep1:GAACGGACACCCAGTGx Blackshaw_E14_rep1:GTCTTCGAGCAGGCTAx 
                                   1                                    1
```

I am curious about what happened here. Are these not quite 1s floating-point errors? Is this how R would display them? Did I not normalize correctly?

Thanks for the help

Comment: [7.31 Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of normalization you want to do, but if you want rowsums to be 1, then what you did seems right to me.

I'm not an expert, but the below gives you a reproducible example where R fails in the way you describe.

```
set.seed(2)
M1 <- matrix(runif(10000,min=0,max=10),nrow=2000)
rowSums(M1)

M2 = t(apply(M1, 1,function(x)(x/sum(x))))
length(which(rowSums(M2)!=1)) # gives 10 unnormalized row
all.equal(rowSums(M2),rep(1,2000),tolerance = .Machine$double.eps) # true
for(idx in which(rowSums(M2) != 1)){
  print(idx)
  print(sum(M2[idx,]),digits = 20)
  print(sum(M2[idx,]) == 1)
  print(all.equal(sum(M2[idx,]),1,tolerance=.Machine$double.eps))
}
```

This prints

```
[1] 422
[1] 0.99999999999999988898
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
...
```

`.Machine$double.eps` is the smallest floating point number x such that 1 + x != 1.  You could retry this experiment with bigger numbers and it looks like the all.equal (which checks if two arrays have all equal entries, entry by entry, within some tolerance) is always true.

If you want to check if all of the rows after your normalization step sum to 1 then you could do so with the `all.equal` function.

Comment: Sweet, it looks like it was a floating-point error since using all.equal() it appears equal to 1

Comment: @Connorr.0 It's NOT a floating point error. It's the normal behavior of any finite computer doing binary arithmetic! Please stop calling it a "floating point error".